# How to select and delete past freehand features in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, tools

I am editing an older map in ArcMap 10.1 and want to edit a freehand drawing someone made. I cannot "select" it or find the shapefile it was made under...

Any advice?

I know how to make my own freehand drawing, but I also need to delete/edit the original one.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are dealing with a graphic so use the **Select** tool on the **Draw** toolbar to select.

Then on the same toolbar under the **Drawing** pulldown you should be able to **Convert Graphics To Features** so that you can edit it.

Alternatively, once you have it selected you can use the **Delete** key (or **Edit | Delete**) to delete it.

**Edit | Select All Elements** will enable you to select all graphics.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the drawing was in layout view and you're in data view or vice versa.  I've done that a few times.